# Numpy can't import even though conda says installed

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-16.04

Numpy somehow stopped working.  I thought it might have been because I changed my `$PATH` env variable, but that doesn't really make sense.  I did run `source`, then `source .bashr` and then `source .bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc` all in a row, so that might have something to do with it.

```
conda list | grep numpy
```

still returns reasonable things

Here is the error it prints when I try to import numpy

```
>>>import numpy as np

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
import apport.fileutils
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

#### EDIT:

I have tried importing all the other packages I have since installed via Conda and none of them have worked either.  They all seem to give similar errors (1. `Error in sys.excepthook:` and 2. `No module named 'apt_pkg'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT:

Big picture:

```
1) Uninstall conda first
2) Again install conda
3) Then install Anaconda from its official documentation.
```

Copy these commands:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
rm -rf anaconda3/                 # uninstall

cd /tmp                           # install
curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
sha256sum Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
# verify legit shell file ^
bash Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
   # hit 'enter'
yes
source ~/.bashrc
conda install -c anaconda numpy   # install packages
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

#### Note:

My system info:
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Hi, do you mind giving the exact commands you used?  Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  Because the versions might be slightly different for 16.04 vs. 14.04 vs. 12.04, etc.  Thanks :)

Comment: you ll have to go through its official documentation. Just google it out. Steps are already mentioned over there. I am in the middle of something that's why I don't have it handy right now